# Custom curve in React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to make a custom curve in React Native. My objective is to do something like this:

[image]

I have been able to do this already:

[image]

I have done this with the following code :

[Here's the present code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-forked-qlpg3?file=/src/App.js)

But i'm not being able to transform the design according to the first image. How can i do that?

Comment: i think it is better to use a background image.

Comment: Actually i need to do some customization on that. So, i need to do this. @SDushan

Comment: See library 'react-native-svg'. You can combine it with 'd3' library.
It not very easy but once you will get it you can do almost any shape you want (and animate them too).